# Overload - not in scope

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors, overloading

I get these errors:

```
circleType.cpp||In function 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, circleType&)':|
circleType.cpp|48|error: 'getRadius' was not declared in this scope|
circleType.cpp|49|error: 'circumference' was not declared in this scope|
circleType.cpp|50|error: 'area' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build finished: 3 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

Errors are found here:

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream& outs, circleType& circle1)
{
   outs << "radius: " << getRadius() << endl
   << "circumference: " << circumference() << endl
   << "area: " << area() << endl;
   return outs;
}
```

As an example, here's the circumference function:

```
double circleType::circumference()
{
    return (radius*2*pi);
}
```

Header file:

```
class circleType
{
public:
    circleType(); // færibreytulaus smiður
    circleType(double the_radius);
    double getRadius();
    void setRadius(double the_radius);
    double area();
    double circumference();
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outs, circleType& );
private:
    double radius;
};
```

Main:

```
circleType circle1(3.0);
cout << "circle1:" << endl;
cout << "--------" << endl;
cout << circle1 << endl;
```

All headers are included everywhere. I'm still a bit confused about the overload function, any help appriciated.

Answer (score 3):

You are not invoking the member functions on the input object (`circle1`); rather, you are trying to invoke some *global* functions with the same names that do not exist (mind the fact that a `friend` function is not a member function of the class it is a friend of, but rather a free, non-member function that has been given access to the class's internals).

To fix the problem, change the definition of your overloaded `operator <<` as follows:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& outs, circleType& circle1)
{
   outs << "radius: " << circle1.getRadius() << endl
   << "circumference: " << circl1.circumference() << endl
   << "area: " << circle1.area() << endl;
   return outs;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, yes. I'm still getting the hang of classes, thank you very much.
Worked like a charm.

Comment: There is though 1 problem I'm still faced with:
What if I want to make circle2, 3, 4, ..., ? Then I obviously can't do: circle1.area()

Comment: @Zanii: I don't understand what you mean. You probably have some misconception about what you're trying to achieve. Play around with these things for a while and you should get the hang of it.

Comment: Let's say I wanted to make the new circleType object that is called circle2. Now I can't use "outs << "radius: " << circle1.getRadius() << endl" since this object is called circle2, not circle1.

Comment: @Zanii: As I thought, you have a misconception. `circle1` is just the name given to the function parameter. If you invoke it with an object named `circle2`, or `bingo`, the object will be still referred to with the name of `circle1` inside the function. This is basics. I suggest you reading some tutorial or introductory book on C++

Comment: Right you are. This is something I should have figured out, better yet, should have known. Thanks again.